# wxPaintDC - Shapes are drawn below current one and not over the current one

Tags: c++, graphics, wxwidgets, paint, shapes

I am trying to implement a program that draws basic shapes. All is going well except that new Shapes are being drawn below the current shape. My Paint function in the frames sourcecode file looks like this:

```
void ShapeFrame::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& event)
{
    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    wxGraphicsContext *gc = wxGraphicsContext::Create(dc);
    wxGraphicsMatrix trans = gc->CreateMatrix();
    setTransform(&trans);

    ShapeData *data = wxGetApp().getData();
    for(int i=0; i<data->getNumShapes(); i++) 
    {
        data->getShape(i)->draw(dc, &trans);
    }
    delete gc;
}
```

A snapshot of the app screen is also given.
I am a beginner in wxWidgets [the circle was drawn first and then the rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N2Kp.jpg)

Comment: That's most probably due to wrong order of `ShapeData` components, which BTW has nothing to do with `wxPaintDC` or wxWidgets in general.

Comment: Are both the circle and the rectangle being drawn by your `ShapeFrame::OnPaint` method? I.e. are they both in the ShapeData array?

Comment: @iwbnwif yes they are both in ShapeData array

Comment: Thanks! The problem was resolved by reversing the for loop (data->getNumShapes()-1 to 0)